# Can't see custom campaign parameter result of Firebase Dynamic Link in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I started to use Firebase Dynamic Link since few days ago with custom campaign parameters like this.

```
https://subdomain.app.goo.gl/?apn=[package_name]&link=[link_url]
  &utm_campaign=campaign&utm_content=content&utm_medium=medium&utm_source=source
```

Few days later, I checked Google Analytics to check new users in `Acquisition > Sources > Google Play` section.
But recorded `Source / Medium` value has been `(not set) / (not set)`.

This looks like campaign parameters isn't taken over to Play Store via Dynamic Link redirection.

Has anyone successfully got expected value?

Comment: I have same issue with you

Comment: I'm trying the same thing now myself. I have verified that the app is getting the utm parameters in the deeplink, but the sources / campaigns set do not then show up in the firebase analytics reports.

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? I encounter the same issues with my campaign parameters. I'd like to see them in the Play Store developer Console.

Comment: Same issue here. Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: @david I am having the same problem, and o enquiry I got a mail from Play Store that it needs 'sufficient data' to generate acquisition reports. With how many visitors/ downloads did you get the data on Play Store?