# Can't see custom campaign parameter result in Firebase Google Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

I have application which use Firebase SDK. I wanna know inflow route to download my app. so I use campaign parameter like this

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zzieut.meu&d=1&utm_campaign=test&utm_medium=zzim_web&utm_source=zzieut`

but I can't see campaign information on my Firebase Analytics. It show `(not set) (net set)`....
I think this is same problem with this post.

Link : 
[Can't see custom campaign parameter result of Firebase Dynamic Link in Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271292/cant-see-custom-campaign-parameter-result-of-firebase-dynamic-link-in-google-an)

How can I analyze my app input information?? :(